# iOS 7 - Update Data Every 24 Hours

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I'm creating an app that needs to check for data once a day (midnight). I know there is a background fetch mode in iOS7, but from what I know there is no way to force it to update in given time interval. Is there any way to do this and still pass the Appstore review?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: sorry for late suggestion but u need to check 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628020/perform-action-if-date-change/26628319#26628319

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not real way to do this, since it requires you app to be running in background. background running modes are restricted to audio, VOIP, location and accessory type apps.

What you could do is just check when you last update data in the app when the user launches the app. This way you will only update data when the user starts your app and also only use data when the user is really using the app.

The background fetching will only work if the user is start your app often and iOS will allow you app to do background fetching. iOS will decide when you app is allowed to do a background refresh and you have little influence over the interval.

> `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum`
>
> The smallest fetchinterval supported by the system.

Comment: Sorry but in iOS 7 there is  a new background fetch API. Which can be activated.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this and was editing my answer. But the question is to update on a set time. Which is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I'm doing exactly what you said. When the user starts the app it checks the last update time and if it is more than 24 hours ago it updates. The app than sends you some notifications based on loaded data. That's why it would be great for user to open the app everyday to load the data but to update them automatically and then just send the notifications.

Comment: Then the new iOS 7 backgroundFetch is something you want to look into. But it should be implement beside the 24 hour check, because the user can turn of the background fetch for your app. Also there is not sure way the fetch will be successful.

Comment: Yeah looks like my only solution. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's not exactly answer you expect but in iOS 7 there is a functionality which allow you to fetch the data every some period of time.
In this scenario iOS intelligently schedules the background fetch events based on your app usage and it helps you save battery life. So this not going to work every 24h but I think you can read the data and if it has been updated refresh the app if not ignore it.
In your Xcode 5 -> Target -> Capabilities turn on Background modes (background fetch).
And in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions add:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
```

This is a method which will be called:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this method and I'm probably going to use it. But I'm currently looking for a way to update data based on time interval.

Comment: I think if you want the user to open the app and have fresh data this is a only way to do that. It's not 100% that the data will be up to dated but you can also run the check every time when user open the app and if it's out of date fetch it.